# CSS - Hide bottom and intentional overlap on top

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I've been learning HTML and CSS for 2 weeks. Right now I am having trouble with the `relative` and `absolute` position. My parent is `relative` and the image is `absolute`, however, every time I resize my browser, the bottom overlaps. How can I make the bottom hide and the top intentionally overlap its parent?

I tried making the height 100vh but the image have a big gap so i just adjusted 68vh my problem is when i adjust the browser that it overlaps

[Screenshot of the overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh7Vt.png)

```
//Parent
#info-5{
    background: url("../img/score-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
    color: var(--white-primary);
    position: relative;
    height: 68vh;

    /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}

//Grid container
#info-5 .info-5-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    height: 100%;
}


//Child
#info-5 .info-5-container img {
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 250px;
}

<section id="info-5" class="p-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-5-container">
            <article>
                <h1 class="l-heading">
                    Calculate my Score
                </h1>
                <h2>Check your credit reports as often as you want, it won't affect your scores.
                </h2>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-orange-primary">Show my score</a>
            </article>
            <img src="img/hand.png" alt="Info 5">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try `overflow: hidden` on the parent

Comment: Hello nomnomcookie, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code to your post. In this case the html part and css. Without that it's not easy to help you out.

Comment: did u try `bottom: 0` for image? this should always position the image above the bottom of parent container.

Comment: I tried bottom: 0. It doesnt work sadly.

Comment: Could you add a snippet that people can use? It's hard to figure out the problem without a working example

Comment: And I meant, try `overflow: hidden` on `.info-5-container`. Did you try it on that element?

Comment: I tried it still overlaps. Here is the full css and html. Let me know if i have things to improve like font sizes and other things. Thanks in advance https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7yruk1shJi

Comment: I got it i just set the bottom to 0 and remove top

Answer (score 0):

Use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px`, `%`, `em` or `rem` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive and no matter what screen size, it will always resize itself.

It will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: I have vh height on the parent not sure if im doing it wrong

Comment: @nomnomcookie `vh` is correct on parent but if you change, `%` and `px` too, then your whole website will be responsive. By adding **Viewport Units** on parent, makes only parent responsive not all other elements. So convert every element in **Viewport Units**. If it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: @nomnomcookie Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?